# How do I send a get request on a change in the database data? Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api, client

This is the story:

I have a database, MS Server and I made a WebAPI that I use from my client-side AngularJS App. The WebAPi manipulates with the database and it has a get request for get all entries from a certain table.

Is there anyway, or any setup that is typical in a situation where a change in the database (adding an entry or editing a entry), a get request can be made to the database then from my client-side, so I can dynamically change my content as changes are made to the database?

What are some solutions? I can change my WebAPi if need be, but I just wanted to see if, and how, this was possible.

Comment: If I'm correct, when you are sending post data which will change entry into db, just inside of .success block make a call of a get function. that will gave you updated data from db.

Comment: But i have many users, what if some user sends a post, that is related to information another user needs? I figured out that web sockets are needed

Comment: if you want dynamically refresh on your database, you can make thread at your back-end which will call your get method every 1 min etc. Java have decent solution for that